# Unexpected behaviour with HERE Route Match Extension

Tags: here-api

I have a question regarding the `Route Match Extension`.

Should I expect any gaps in the `GPS` trace to be snapped to the road network as the most probable route, or to be represented as a straight line from `A` to `B`?

[image: ExampleTrace]

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not expect any gaps here. The Route Match Extension works well with these locations. I reproduced it on a local demo (same gap between #3 and #4):

[image]

You should not use a different map source for displaying.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I don't think that the mapping provider is the issue. The points that are being displayed on my map where returned from the RME. To generate the line that you've displayed it must have interpolated the points between 3 and 4? Is there a setting that needs to be enabled to do this because i've never noticed the RME response contain additional points?

Comment: Matched points returned from RME: `55.00105,-1.53399
55.00106,-1.53407
55.00090,-1.53435
55.00100,-1.53435
55.00100,-1.53435
55.00100,-1.53435
55.00100,-1.53435
55.00100,-1.53435
55.00100,-1.53435
55.00100,-1.53435
55.00099,-1.53435
55.00045,-1.53897
55.00040,-1.53924
55.00034,-1.53957
55.00039,-1.53994
55.00047,-1.54015
55.00040,-1.54047
55.00034,-1.54073
55.00019,-1.54127
55.00015,-1.54144
55.00007,-1.54175
55.00001,-1.54198
54.99992,-1.54232
54.99984,-1.54263`

Comment: The points between the 3 and four has been interpolated by the RME. There is an extended demo available which you can use for testing: https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/rme_trip_anomalies_detection

Comment: Next to the input files you can also add points via mouse click